# Python - BeautifulSoup - Non English characters not read properly

Tags: python, html, utf-8, character-encoding, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to extract data from an HTML page using BeautifulSoup, but characters in other languages are not read correctly.

Code i'm using:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup("C:\Myfile.html","html.parser")
htmlText=soup.body.get_text()
```

Error example: ß is printed as ÃŸ

Meta of the html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8 ">
```

I've also tried `soup.decode("utf-8")`

Using Python 3.6

Why does this happen?
Kindly help.

Comment: You coud read the file (encoded in utf-8) and pass its content in the constructor `open("myfile", "r", encoding="utf-8").read()`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!